Custom CSS throws Unhandled Error in Blazor WASM Standalone
I have a new Blazor WASM Standalone project targeting .NET 9 that works fine. It's a new project so it doesn't have much in it.
I added my own custom css file to the project and referenced in index.html and now I get the following message with not much else for information.

An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

I don't see any related error messages in the console either.
When I started getting this error, I removed all my new modifications and started adding them one at a time. Adding references to Google font files or the latest version of Bootstrap didn't cause any issues. The error popped up when I referenced the css file in index.html which looks like below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My New App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:ital,opsz,wght@0,14..32,100..900;1,14..32,100..900&family=Manrope&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> /* Changed the reference from app.css to style.css */
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="Ingrid.Web.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="." class="reload">Reload</a>
        <span class="dismiss"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> /* I also added this to use the latest version of Bootstrap */
</body>

</html>

Any idea what maybe causing this issue?
P.S. My css file is also a new file and doesn't have much in it. It contains fairly basic css classes and it's already minified.

There could be several issues here.

Check the path for css-file is correct. 2. Does Console throw any error?


I simply replaced app.css with style.css and they're both in the same folder so the path to CSS is correct. As per additional error info, as mentioned in the original post, I see nothing specific in the console.

can you upload the code somewhere I can download it from?

I just created a new  Blazor WASM Standalone, I have no issue:
https://paste.ofcode.org/knxXWbGCKyiMn5C24apKbb

In .net 9 for static assets you should use <ImportMap /> . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#net-9-or-later. Have you tried just simply force reloading the browser, if you have only just changed a name. Has the icon path always been like that?

I figured out the issue. My new custom css didn't have the blazor-error-ui, reload, etc. classes used by the <div> that is displayed when an error occurs. Though I was a bit surprised that a missing css class would throw an error like that, I'm actually happy that Blazor gives us a warning about such simple yet important situations. Thank you all for your help!
